# Vue unshift only repeats the last item

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

My problem is same as this issue:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-unshift-only-repeats-the-last-item

I have an array like this:

```
remate: {id:1, lotes: [{id:1, nombre: lalala}, {id:2, nombre: lololo}]}
```

when I try put new items to remate.lotes the push work as expected, it push the new data to end of array but I need put the data to position 0 of array and here is the problem... the array is broken and put again my last array result.

Here a video to show exact what happen to understand better and show the code.

https://vimeo.com/266804712

I dont understand where is the problem.

pd: I try put :key to my component but without results.

Updated:

```
Page:
<loteForm :Remate="remate" key="loteFormNew"></loteForm>

<template v-for="(lote, index) in remate.lotes"> 
     <Lote :Remate="remate" :Lote="lote" :key="'lote' + index"></Lote>     
    <hr> 
</template>


Component loteForm:
export default {     
    name: 'Form',         
    components: {             
        'LoteFormClientes': LoteFormClientes,         
    },        
    props: {             
        Remate: {                 
            required: true,            
        },             
        Lote: {     
            required: false,     
        },        
    },         
    data () {        
        return {        
            form: new Form(this.Lote),       
        }     
    },       
    methods: {       
        async loteForm(){       
            this.form['remate_id'] = this.Remate.id;        
            const { data } = await this.form.post('/api/form/lote');     
            console.log(this.Lote);         
            if(this.Lote === undefined) {
                //work as expected
                this.Remate.lotes.push(data)              
                //not working
                this.Remate.lotes.unshift(data)              
            }                
        }       
   },      
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you're attempting to use in your question

Comment: Please add the code for the `unshift()` part

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, it is recommended that you put the error directly inside your question, as some people are on commercial machines, and they don't have control over their volume, this is a problem for a link to a video, as they might not know if the video or the advertisement is going to make a sound. I also suggest you quote the contents of the other site that has your problem, as its annoying for many people to go to that site to see the problem, then go back to your code to search then going back to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element is being added to the array, but it is not being rendered because Vue tries to change the DOM as little as possible.

In other words, use a `key` that is bound to each element. Use:

```
:key="'lote' + lote.id"
```

Not

```
:key="'lote' + index"
```

Because using index is no good, as the second element in the array will always have `lote1` as index, no matter it's value (and when you `.unshift` a new one, although there's a new element at position 1, the index didn't change, so Vue does not re-render a new element).

Changed `v-for`:

```
<template v-for="(lote, index) in remate.lotes">  
    <Lote :Remate="remate" :Lote="lote" :key="'lote' + lote.id"></Lote>
    <hr>
</template>
```

Comment: I try putting the key :key="'lote' + lote.id" but it don't work, I need put the key into child component of Lote too?

Comment: You need to put the key in the component that is `v-for`'ed. Are you sure `lote.id`s are unique?

Comment: Yes, its an autoincrement bd:

<loteForm :Remate="remate" key="loteFormNew"></loteForm> <template v-for="(lote, index) in remate.lotes">     <Lote :Remate="remate" :Lote="lote" :key="'lote' + lote.id"></Lote>     <hr> </template>

Comment: Thanks acdcjunior, the :key option is the solution I need learn more how implement the component because I have a terrible disorganization on my project it make the vuejs reuse the same objects...